# Java IO Thread Saftey

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, io, bytebuffer

I use [MappedByteBuffers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html) to achieve thread safety between readers and writers of a file via volatile variables (writer updates position and readers read the writer's position) (this is a file upload system, the the incoming file is a stream, if that matters). There are more tricks, obviously (sparse files, power of two mapping growth), but it all boils down to that.

I can't find a faster way to write to a file while concurrently reading the same without caching the same completely in memory (which I cannot do due to shear size).

Is there any other method of IO that guarantees visibility within the same process for readers to written bytes? MappedByteBuffer makes its guarantees, indirectly, via the Java Memory Model, and I'd expect any other solution to do the same (read: non platform specific and more).

Is this the fastest way? Am I missing something in the docs?

Comment: is there really any formal guarantee regarding direct ByteBuffer and JMM?

Comment: zhong.j.yu, Volatile reads emit appropriate memory barriers and the MBB writes directly to memory. I've not been able to find it formally documented, but it follows from the core rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some tests quite a few years ago on what was then decent hardware, and `MappedByteBuffer` was about 20% faster than any other I/O technique. It does have the disadvantage for writing that you need to know the file size in advance.

Comment: I use a thin wrapper that gives you power-of-two sized MBBs starting at 1K up to 2GB as needed. It starts with a sparse file backing it which is the best guess of the size (the correct guess in my case, but it need not be) and then truncate to size. No unneeded disk activity if you guess at least large enough aside from the single extra metadata write for truncation. No penalty for guessing too large. Works a treat.